How to make GRUB set the root device as the EFI booted device?
XY problem: I have multiple Debian Live OSes (made through live-build) on multiple drives in my system, but whichever drive is booted to it just loads the squashFS from the first drive.
It looks like the boot=live parameter is looking for the files in the /live directory (which contains filesystem.squashfs), however it appears that GRUB is just getting this folder from the root device (which is seemingly static depending on how the BIOS sees the drives) and not the device which is chosen to be booted from*.
Is there a way to make GRUB set the root device as the drive which the EFI booted to? Or is there another scalable/non-hardcoded way to load the desired squashFS?
*It's also a bit odd because when the live OS is 'burnt' to the drive there is no option in the EFI to boot to the drive, yet it is still bootable 

UEFI boots from the ESP - efi system partition. Typically that has a tiny 3 line grub.cfg to boot a full grub.cfg in an install. With USB flash drives it boots from the ESP but /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which loads grub. I boot many ISO directly from grub, but have to manually create a grub.cfg with correct path & grub entries. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multiboot_USB_drive  & https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/live-boot-doc/live-boot.7.en.html & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

What you are talking about is mostly decided by Debian kernel / initrd / init scripts. Grub can at most pass something along on the kernel cmdline. So it depends on which additional configuration parameters Debian might support here to narrow it down. Unfortunately these scripts are quite difficult to read and I'm not familiar with them. live-boot suggests bootfrom= and/or LIVE_GENERATE_UUID=1 (and there should be a .disk/live-uuid* or similar file? Not sure!). You could also ask on Debian's mailing lists.

Thanks both. I was able to sort the XY problem after some trouble shooting and documentation reading. I'll add an answer to the XY problem. I might have misspoken when I said which the EFI boots to - by this I mean when selecting the boot device from within the BIOS setup or quick boot menu.

With some direction from ChatGPT I've been able to solve the XY problem after some troubleshooting as to how the squashFS is being found and loaded. I broke into the initramfs during the boot process (break=mount as a GRUB boot option) and did a listing of disks with ls -l /dev/disk/by-label. Indeed the first device the systems seems (also the GRUB root) appears to be where the initramfs is searching for filesystem.squashfs. This can be overriden by means of the bootfrom boot argument being set to the location of the device containing the desired filesystem (e.g. bootfrom=/dev/disk/by-label/live-os-1).
To set the label assigned to the live ISO, an lb config item of --iso-volume can be used. This solution is scalable because it allows this configuration all within auto/config and no other hardcoding is necessary.
Example snippet of auto/config:
name=live-os-1

lb config noauto \
    --bootappend-live "boot=live bootfrom=/dev/disk/by-label/$name" \
    --iso-volume $name \

